# yii tab background image possible to make it display?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions

Is that possible to set tab background image for yii/yii2 framework? Not change the background color or font. Is that change it as CSS too? Any example can refer?

[image]

Comment: update your question and show the view code for these tabs

Comment: just want to know is that possible to change the background color for these tabs when mouse over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes is possible

tipically the tabs forms  in Yii2 are based on bootstrap3 css  tempalete so can use label (non encode) for assign the img istead of label text

```
echo Tabs::widget([
'items' => [
    [
        'label' => '<img src="your_source_url/your_image.jpg">',
        'encode' =>false,
        'active' => true
    ],
```

or for bakground color you can use the option  assigning the style (or the class) you prefere

```
echo Tabs::widget([
'items' => [
    [
        'label' => 'my_label',
        'options' => ['style' ='background-color: red;]
        'active' => true
    ],
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-tabs.html#$items-detail